# Copyright/Watermark many images with different resolutions (with ImageMagick)

Tags: image, resize, imagemagick

i am trying to solve the following problem:

I have one picture *logo.png* with a resolution of 1260x1580. I want to use this to copyright different JPG-Images, e.g. *image1.jpg* with a resolution of 1280x853. I want to have the logo e.g. at the bottom right and **always with a height of e.g. 1/8 of the height of the JPG-Image**.

Short: I have many images with different resolutions and the copyright should have always the same proportion (e.g. 1/8 of the total heigth) within that image.

I am using ImageMagick on command-line (on Windows 10), at the moment like this:

`magick image1.jpg logo.png -resize x%[fx:u.h/8] -gravity SouthEast -geometry +15+15 -composite outfile.jpg`

Unfortunately the resize-Option with `x%[fx:u.h/8]` doesn't work like expected, it also resizes the JPG-Image *image1.jpg*. I don't know, how i can manage it to resize only the *logo.png* and let the size of *image1.jpg* untouched. When i put `( logo.png -resize x%[fx:u.h/4] )` in brackets of course `u.h` then refers to *logo.png*, this is also wrong :-/

It would be great if you can assist me a little bit to find the right command for my purpose... Thanks for your replies and help!

PS: I hope that i didn't ignored some important source or help, but i can't find the solution by myself - sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a stack of two images, the main input and the logo. You can have your "-resize" operation work on just the logo by adding a condition to the FX expression. Start your command with something like this...

```
 magick image1.jpg logo.png -resize x%[fx:t==1?u[0].h/8:u[0].h] ...
```

The expression runs once for each image in the stack. The "t" substitutes for the position of the image in the stack, the first image is 0, the second is 1. So if "t" equals 1, it's the logo. Resize it to 1/8 the height of the first image indicated by "u[0].h/8". Otherwise resize it to "u[0].h", which is already the height of the first image, so it won't change that one.

Answer (score 1):

In Imagemagick, try simply using parenthesis to limit the operation

```
magick image1.jpg ( logo.png -resize x%[fx:u.h/8] ) -gravity SouthEast -geometry +15+15 -composite outfile.jpg
```

Comment: The "u.h" inside the parentheses will refer to the height of the logo image, and resize it to 1/8 of its current height. If the task is to resize the logo to 1/8 the height of the main input image, you'd have to do something like set the height as a variable with "-set option:logosize %[fx:u.h/8]" right after reading in the main input, then inside the parentheses do "logo.png -resize x%[logosize]".

Comment: @GeeMack,  Good Point! I overlooked that. `magick image1.jpg -set option:logosize "%[fx:u.h/8]" ( logo.png -resize "x%[logosize]" ) -gravity SouthEast -geometry +15+15 -composite outfile.jpg`

Comment: Thansk alot this wokrs for me on Linux `magick nonam.webp \( $logo -resize x%[fx:u.h/8] \) -gravity northeast -geometry +1+1  -composite output.png`